# ear war and location of properties

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, classpath, war, ear

I have an ear file with the following structure

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/application.xml
META-INF/build.properties
doi-ejb.jar
doi-web.war
lakshmi-ejb.jar
lakshmi-std-cmp-ejb.jar
lib/
lib/commons-1.0.jar
lib/commons-web-1.0.jar
lib/doi-int-test-lib.jar
lib/doi-lib.jar
lib/doi-unit-test-lib.jar
lib/lakshmi-lib.jar
lib/lakshmi-std-cmp-lib.jar
```

the war file (`doi-web.war`) contains

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/ch/[...]
WEB-INF/classes/common-messages.properties
WEB-INF/classes/common-messages_de.properties
WEB-INF/classes/common-messages_it.properties
WEB-INF/classes/commons.properties
WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties
WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml
WEB-INF/web.xml
resources/
resources/css/[...]
resources/images/[...]
resources/scripts/
view/[...]
```

I can deploy the ear file without any error in Glassfish:

```
[...]

javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web || WEB0671: Loading application [doi#doi-web.war] at [/doi]
javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin || doi was successfully deployed in 5,251 milliseconds.
```

If I try to launch the application I get:

```
[...]
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name /commons, locale en_US
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:705)
at ch.ethz.id.wai.web.controller.ApplicationSettingsController.setup(ApplicationSettingsController.java:25)
... 67 more
```

Now as I understood this means that `/commons.properties` should be in the classpath. Should'n the `WEB-INF/classes` directory be in the classpath? The `WEB-INF` directory is read by Glassfish since the `web.xml` file is recognized.

Comment: Well a quick check to see if in fact there's a issue because of war inside ear, or if indeed gf can't find the file in the classpath is to deploy the war all by itself and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @ShivanDragon Actually I cannot: after upgrading to Glassfish 3.1.2 I was no more able to deploy an ear file without the war file (since in applications.xml I specify a web module). I am then trying to embed it in the ear file. But then I cannot deploy the war file alone since it already loaded (as part of the ear file)